# Verify the set is a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to solve this problem in a text book regarding vector spaces. I'm completely lost at this point on how to approach this, so could someone please help me out?

> W is the set of all vectors in $ R^3 $ whose third component is -1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method of all: a vector space must contain the zero vector, in this case $(0,0,0)$.  But it doesn't because the third component is not $-1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more about the it? Specifically the last part about the "third component is not -1" part?

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $W$ as follows

$$ W = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z = -1 \} $$

Claim: $W$ is $\mathbf{NOT}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. To see this, consider the vectors $\mathbf{v} = (1,1,-1)$ and $\mathbf{w} = (0,0,-1)$. Notice, $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \in W$. However, $\mathbf{v + w} = (1,1,-2) \notin W $. Hence, $W$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest reason is : $(0,0,0) \not \in W$.